# How to receive controller touch_pad information in three.js webXR

Tags: three.js, webvr, webxr

I am a Japanese student. Sorry if my English is strange.
I want to add an event that accompanies the controller pad information by webXR in three.js
I want to add an event that when the pad part of the controller is moved, the displayed object is also moved.
I am using HTCVIVE.
The events for the trigger button operations are in the official example, but I can't find any other button operations in the example.
I did some research and found that as of June 2020, webXR cannot get information about the pad? Is this situation still the same?
I have a code that works with the now deprecated WebVR.
It looks like it is written this way.
And I have confirmed that this code does not work in webXR

this is code work in webVRAPI

```
controller1.addEventListener('axischanged', move);
.
.
.
function move(event){
    if(this.getButtonState('thumbpad') && this.getButtonState('trigger') === false){
      var z = event.axes[0];
      var x = event.axes[1];
      group.position.x = group.position.x + 100 * x;
      group.position.z = group.position.z + 100* z;
    }
    if(this.getButtonState('thumbpad') && this.getButtonState('trigger')){
      var y = -event.axes[1];
      group.position.y = group.position.y + 100* y;
    }
  }
```